# Cant Create handler inside thread problem in gps detetction

Tags: android

I have Used this Program for taking Gps periodically but i got exception in that, please give me solution

```
     package com.excerciseTest;



     import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.Calendar;
     import java.util.List;
     import java.util.Locale;
     import java.util.Timer;
     import java.util.TimerTask;



     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.app.AlarmManager;
     import android.app.NotificationManager;
     import android.app.PendingIntent;
     import android.app.Service;
     import android.content.Context;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.location.Address;
     import android.location.Geocoder;
     import android.location.Location;
     import android.location.LocationListener;
     import android.location.LocationManager;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.os.CountDownTimer;
     import android.os.IBinder;
     import android.os.Looper;
     import android.util.Log;
     import android.widget.Toast;

    public class GpsService extends Service{
            private Long counter = 0L; 
        private Timer timer = new Timer();
        private final Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
        private LocationManager locationManager;
        private Location currentLocation;

       @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;


}
@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
    super.onCreate();
    /*Intent intent = new Intent(this, RepeatingAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);



    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), 10 * 1000,pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    */

    try
    {

        _startService();
        //Set Starting point of latitude and longitude
        /*
        counter=0L;
        new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) { 

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { 

                locationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", (long)30000, (float) 10.0, new LocationListener()
                {
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) 
                    {


                            counter++;
                            System.out.println(counter);
                            handleLocationChanged(arg0);
                            /*

                            System.out.println("latitude"+lati.get(0).toString());
                            System.out.println("langitude"+lati.get(1).toString());


                            /*
                            if(counter==1)
                            {
                                checklatAt0=getLatitude();
                                checklonat0=getLongitude(); 
                                System.out.println("Latitude At 0"+checklatAt0);
                                System.out.println("Longitude At 0"+checklonat0);



                            }   
                            if(counter==300)
                            {

                                checklatAt300=getLatitude();
                                checklonat300=getLongitude();
                                System.out.println("Latitude At 300"+checklatAt300);
                                System.out.println("Longitude At 300"+checklonat300);
                                counter = 0L;


                            }   
                           System.out.println(counter);


                           counter++;


            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });




                //mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000); 
            } 

            public void onFinish() { 
                //mTextField.setText("done!"); 
            } 
         }.start(); 
        */



    /*
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                new TimerTask(){ 

                    public void run() 
                    {
            /// Subscribe to the location manager's updates on the current location
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", (long)30000, (float) 10.0, new LocationListener()
                        {
                            public void onLocationChanged(final Location arg0) 
                            {



                                    ArrayList lati=handleLocationChanged(arg0);


                                    System.out.println(lati.get(0).toString());
                                    System.out.println(lati.get(1).toString());



                                    if(counter==1)
                                    {
                                        checklatAt0=getLatitude();
                                        checklonat0=getLongitude(); 
                                        System.out.println("Latitude At 0"+checklatAt0);
                                        System.out.println("Longitude At 0"+checklonat0);



                                    }   
                                    if(counter==300)
                                    {

                                        checklatAt300=getLatitude();
                                        checklonat300=getLongitude();
                                        System.out.println("Latitude At 300"+checklatAt300);
                                        System.out.println("Longitude At 300"+checklonat300);
                                        counter = 0L;


                                    }   
                                   System.out.println(counter);


                                   counter++;


                    }

                    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });

                    }
                        }, 0, 1000L);
    */

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void _startService() {
    counter=0L;
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
          new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

              counter++;
              getLocatonUpdate(getApplicationContext());


            }
          },
          0,
          1000);
      Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Timer started!!!");
    }

@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
    // Cancel the persistent notification.

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed at " + time.getTime() + "; counter is at: " + counter, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public void getLocatonUpdate(Context c)
{
    locationManager=(LocationManager)c.getSystemService(c.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", (long)30000, (float) 10.0, new LocationListener()
    {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) 
        {



                System.out.println(counter);
                handleLocationChanged(arg0);



        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    });



}

private void handleLocationChanged(Location loc)
{

        this.currentLocation = loc;
        // Update the latitude & longitude TextViews
        System.out.println(Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()));
        System.out.println(Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()));




    }



 }
```

And this is exception

```
       02-11 19:05:06.930: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(614): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
      02-11 19:05:06.930: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(614): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't     
      create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

      02-11 19:05:06.930: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(614):     at android.os.Handler.<init>   
      (Handler.java:121)

      02-11 19:05:06.930: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(614):     at  
      android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.<init>(LocationManager.java:173)

      02-11 19:05:06.930: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(614):     at 
      android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.<init>(LocationManager.java:173)

     02-11 19:05:06.930: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(614):     at 
      android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:579)

    02-11 19:05:06.930: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(614):     at 
     android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:446)

    02-11 19:05:06.930: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(614):     at 
    com.excerciseTest.GpsService.getLocatonUpdate(GpsService.java:262)
   02-11 19:05:06.930: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(614):     at   
   com.excerciseTest.GpsService$1.run(GpsService.java:239)

   02-11 19:05:06.930: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(614):     at 
    java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take the call to `getLocatonUpdate` out of the `TimerTask`.

The exception is being raised because `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates` must be called from a `Looper` thread such as the main thread (see [docs for LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)).

The timer thread is not a `Looper` thread.  You could make it one, but it's not needed: `requestLocationUpdates()` already notifies your callback periodically.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens when you create multiple threads and want to update the UI from one of these threads.

You need to create a `Handler` to to send and catch messages from different threads into the main UI thread(Activity class) in order to use the methods you have defined in that Activity class.

For an example of how to use handlers in threads, Android have given an example for [creating ProgressDialogs with a second thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog), if you exand the "Example ProgressDialog with a second thread" title in that section.

You have to use the same ideology in your code aswell.